# Not working json data in Template with vue js

Tags: templates, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I can not pass the json data in the template correctly. I try in any way I can not find. If you want everything in a snippet I can put it. Thank you in advance.

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
 <cols :pops="pops"></cols>
</div>
```

**My App:**

```
var main = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        pops: [],
    },
    mounted: function () {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
    url: '../assets/data/pop.json',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        self.pops = data;
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    });
    },
```

**In same file (app)**

```
Vue.component('cols', {
    template:
        `<li v-for="pop in pops"><a href="#"> <b>{{ pop.Commune }}</b><span>{{ pop.Population }}</span><div  :style="{width: ( pop.Population/520504 * 100) + '%'}"></div></a></li>`,
});
```

**ERROR**

- Property or method "pops" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
- The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.

Comment: Why do you have those properties in `components`?

Comment: Try solution found on different forum.. I'm beginner on vue js.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually passing the data properties to the  component (and the others).

In your HTML try to do this:

```
<div id="app">
 <headermain></headermain>
 <search></search>
 <cols :pops="pops"></cols>
</div>
```

Injecting the data.pops in the pops property of the cols component.